# Cant reset my wordpress password anyhow

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created an azure website with wordpress installed, I have been able to work on it for more than one year but since I didnt use it for some time I forgot my password.

I found how to reset the password via phpmyadmin or mysql but the user id and password I have in the connection strings does not have permission to update the wp_users table.

I tried to insert a new user and I also had the same issue

UPDATE command denied to user 'bd0ca9751c6a7x'@'23.xx.165.199' for table 'wp_users'

I also noticed the status on the table for that user is 0, I suppose 0 is disabled and 1 is enabled, probably for many login attempts?

I tried to use the forgot password functionality but it says mail function has been disabled.

I dont have an azure support plan to ask them for help

Comment: You've got a lot of problems here. One is you don't have a MySQL account with sufficient privileges and nobody here can help you with that. Unless you can find that username and password you're stuck.

Comment: Can you upload files or modified files? You can force the login using php.

Comment: yes I can upload files, if the mysql account doesnt have priviliges, how could I add blog posts to? is Only wp_users restricted?

Comment: @user1811893 how can I forcé using php? please paste the code and where i need to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit files, you can paste this code in your functions file and force the login for the admin.

```
if(isset($_GET['force_login_token']) && $_GET['force_login_token'] == 'NyMnZ7f5dFJFXGLc'){
    $user_id = 1; // admin ID
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
    if( $user ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is not safe leave it there, but see if it helps

Comment: in which file should I put this?

Comment: Anywhere in your functions.php - \wp-content\themes\theme_foder\functions.php